# Created a class and demo for a program that takes 3 employees' info and lists them. However, I can't get it to print out properly

Tags: java

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private int idNumber;
    private String department;
    private String position;

    public Employee(String name, int idNumber, String department, String position)//constructor
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
        this.department = department;
        this.position = position;
    }
    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public String getDepartment ()
    {
        return department;
    }
    public String getPosition ()
    {
        return position;
    }
    public int getIdNumber ()
    {
        return idNumber;
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EntryForm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("-- Employee Entry Form --");

        Employee[] employeeArray = new Employee[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter name");
            String name = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter ID");
            int idNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

            keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter department");
            String department = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter position");
            String position = keyboard.nextLine();

            Employee myEmployee = new Employee(name, idNumber, department, position);
            employeeArray[i] = myEmployee;
        }

        System.out.printf("Name\t ID\t Department\t Position\n");

        for (Employee myEmployee : employeeArray){

            System.out.printf(myEmployee.getName(),"%5d" + myEmployee.getIdNumber(),"%5d"+ myEmployee.getDepartment(), "%5d" + myEmployee.getPosition(),"\n");
        }

    }
}
```

---

Here's where I am having the issue. It won't print out all 3 employees' info.

It's supposed to print out like this.

```
        Name           ID   Department     Position\n
  Bill Gates         1234  Engineering     Engineer\n
   Elon Musk         4443     Business          CEO\n
  Steve Jobs         9999     Creative     Designer\n
```

But Mine prints like this:

```
Name     ID  Department  Position
Bill GatesElon MuskSteve Jobs
```

Comment: Printf takes a format string, then parameters to substitute into the format string. See https://www.cs.colostate.edu/~cs160/.Spring16/resources/Java_printf_method_quick_reference.pdf

Comment: When a method gives unexpected results, read the Javadoc!

Answer (score 1):

That's not how `System.out.printf` works. The **first** argument is the format string, and all the other arguments 'fill in' the values for each `%x` used in the format string.

Your first parameter is the name, so that's the format string, and then the rest fill in the values. Given that the name is e.g. `Bill Gates`, which includes zero `%x` style 'fill value in here' placeholders, **all those further arguments are entirely ignored**.

You're looking for, presumably:

```
String.format("%20s%6d %20s %20s\n", name, id, department, position);
```

Note that your setup cannot work: You use a tab to separate things, but you have no idea what tab does (it's operating system, user settings, and phase of the moon dependent), so there's no way to align things when using tabs. Forget tabs, use `%20s` and co: That will append whatever amount of spaces is required (on the left, i.e. the text becomes right-aligned) in order to print 20 characters. Only if the value you insert is longer than that, will your formatting break, but then, what else can `printf` do? If you want to turn `Joe Beauregard van Houten-Jenkins the Third, Esquire.` into `Joe Beauregard van Hæ…`, you'd have to write code. Something like:

```java
String n = name.length() > 20 ? (name.substring(0, 19) + "…") : name;
```

Thus, something like:

```
void printHeader() {
  System.out.printf("%20s %4s %20s %20s\n", "Name", "ID", "Department", "Position");
```

The numbers in your header format string match the numbers in your actual 'print a line of data'. The only difference is that you use e.g. `%d` when you want a number. Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) on which letters you can stick after that % and what they mean.

Comment: I don't think I understand